# PhotoGallery doesn't scroll in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer

The photobanner doesn't scroll in IE but it does scroll in Chrome and Firefox.

I have searched Google and cannot figure out what is wrong.

Here is a link to the page:

http://www.uncg.edu/~cwdicken/IndProject/Index.html

```
 * {margin: 0; padding: 0;}

body {
    background: url('bg.jpg');
}

#container {
    width: 1000px;
    height: 500px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 50px auto;
    background: url('divback.jpg');
    background-size:1000px 500px;
    position:relative;
}

#header{
    width: 800px;
    margin: 50px auto;
}

#header h1 {
    text-align: center;
    font: 100 60px/1.5 Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;

}

#header p {
    font: 100 15px/1.5 Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    text-align: justify;
}


.photobanner {
    height: 500px;
    width: 3550px;
    top:15%;
    position:relative;


}

/*keyframe animations*/
.first {
    -webkit-animation: bannermove 30s linear infinite;
       -moz-animation: bannermove 30s linear infinite;
        -ms-animation: bannermove 30s linear infinite;
         -o-animation: bannermove 30s linear infinite;
            animation: bannermove 30s linear infinite;
}



@-moz-keyframes bannermove {
 0% {
   margin-left: 0px;
 }
 100% {
   margin-left: -2125px;
 }

}

@-webkit-keyframes bannermove {
 0% {
   margin-left: 0px;
 }
 100% {
   margin-left: -2125px;
 }

}

@-ms-keyframes bannermove {
 0% {
   margin-left: 0px;
 }
 100% {
   margin-left: -2125px;
 }

}

@-o-keyframes bannermove {
 0% {
   margin-left: 0px;
 }
 100% {
   margin-left: -2125px;
 }

}
@keyframes bannermove {
 0% {
    margin-left: 0px;
 }
 100% {
    margin-left: -2125px;
 }

}

.photobanner {
    height: 233px;
    width: 3550px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.photobanner img {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.photobanner img:hover {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg) scale(1.5);
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg) scale(1.5);
    -o-transform: rotate(360deg) scale(1.5);
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg) scale(1.5);
    transform: rotate(360deg) scale(1.5);
    cursor: pointer;

    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
```

Comment: include photobanner CSS and JS/Jquery code you may have in your question so we can get a better idea. Best guess is that IE needs some specific Code to get the thing moving

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fiddle working: http://jsfiddle.net/3hurmyL1/3/

```
.photobanner {
    height: 500px;
    width: 3550px;
    margin-left: 0;
}
@-webkit-keyframes bannermove {
 0% { margin-left: 0; }
 100% {  margin-left: -2125px; }
}
@keyframes bannermove {
 0% { margin-left: 0; }
 100% {  margin-left: -2125px; }
}
/*keyframe animations*/
.first { 
    -webkit-animation: bannermove 30s linear infinite;
    animation: bannermove 30s linear infinite; 
}
```

- You don't have to add all browser properties anymore;
- You added quotes "" when you called your keyframes name and you shouldn't :)

Hope it's help :)

Comment: Your fiddle is not working for me in Chrome.

I removed the quotes from the "bannermove", but it still doesn't work in IE.

The rotation works, but not the scrolling.

Comment: Ok my bad i didn't checked on every browser:
http://jsfiddle.net/3hurmyL1/3/ This is working for me on every brower (IE11) I edited my answer :)

Comment: Ok, Now can you make it rotate 360 when someone hovers over the image.

In Chrome and Firefox the CSS behaves exactly like I want, but it doesn't in IE.

I want the gallery to scroll, and when someone hovers over an image, it scales up and rotates 360 degree.

Comment: I think you should take a look at www.caniuse.com to see if you can use the property you want on the specific browser :)

Comment: Thanks for your help, this is still unsolved.

Can you look at the code I posted above to seee if there is aconflict preventing the scroll in IE?